Is it appropriate to use the native spelling of my country's name ("Brasil") when speaking or writing in English?
As a Brazilian native, I often refer to my country as "Brasil," which is the Portuguese spelling with an 's'. When I am speaking or writing in English, I wonder whether it's appropriate or correct to use "Brasil" instead of the English spelling "Brazil" (with a 'z').
My questions are:

What are the established guidelines or conventions in English
regarding the use of a country's native name versus its Anglicized
version?
Does using "Brasil" in English affect clarity or
understanding among English speakers who might not be familiar with
the Portuguese spelling?
Are there any style guides or linguistic
references that address the correctness of using native spellings in
English communication?

I am looking for factual information, references, or citations that can help me understand the appropriate usage in this context.

Closely related: Why does English have city and country names that differ from the local language?. It's so close in form that it hardly matters, but 'when in Rome' is the usual advice. Paris / Munich / Cologne / Rome // Germany /  Spain / not Londres or Angleterre..

I find it interesting, because its a phenomenon that exists even within countries, here in Brazil, in my home town of Paraty, we spell it using Y, while in almost all of the rest of Brazil, they spell it with an i (parati), the only moment where spelling these words that have such a small difference would be important is during extra-formal emails, where even the chance of being seen as unprofessional might ruin it.

You probably want to wait a day for more answers to come in before accepting the first one. Waiting will encourage other answers that might be better or address issues that were not thought of in the eariler answers.

Why have you written say — which means "pronounce" — when you meant to write write — which means spell out with letters? These are two different things altogether.  The Portuguese pronunciation tends to be [bɾaˈziʊ̯] or [bɾɐˈziɫ].

Only if you want to sound like a Brazilian speaking English.

Writing "Brasil" is probably OK, "Россия" probably not, "中国" definitely not.

The word 'correct' covers a lot of ground.
And there is a difference between speaking vocally and writing by hand.
First, 'correctness'. Usually correct means that there is some rule (which presumably everyone follows. But it can also mean 'what almost everyone does consistently'. When these are different happens when there is a socially preferred dialect, and a dialect that is denigrated.
You can say things 'correctly' in the non-prestige dialect, eg "I ain't so dumb" is the way to say it and not "I not am so dumb", but people in the prestige dialect, snobs and school teachers, will turn their noses up at it. (For the record, the school teachers just want to maintain a standard, and the snobs are just doing it distastefully).
So sometimes it means whether you teacher gives you points for it or takes them away (ie it adheres to a consensus choice that sometimes has arbitrary rules that must be followed to get points on an exam), sometimes it means 'what the majority of people say currently, sometimes it means just being understood (whatever the variation from the usual is expressed). And any one of these will depend on the context of who the speaker is, who the listener is, and the social situation.
In English, the 'correct' pronunciation by English speaking people for English speaking people is /brə'zɪl/ (that's [IPA], the /z/ is voiced, and /ɪ/ is the short i).
In Brazilian Portuguese (what I presume you native language is), the 'correct' pronunciation by Brazilians for Brazilians is /bɾaˈziw/ (the 's' is also voiced).
In a totally Brazilian context you would write an 's' and pronounce it as /z/ (voiced).
In a totally English context you would write a 'z' and also pronounce it as a /z/ (voiced).
When two different contexts apply in a social situation, it's kind of a mess - you have to choose (otherwise it will be weird to all listeners/readers).
Which context's rules (= most common patterns) do you follow? The speaker's? The listener's? Are you doing this in the speaker's milieu or the listener's (where others might judge)? Also, whatever intellectual justification one might give to these choices, what is the current fashion for any of these choices?
Speech or writing these are the possibilities but which one to choose might be different.
This was abstract but we can make it more tangible in your circumstance.
If this were writing, there is an expectation that there are many others who might read this who are English readers. So I would probably write 'z'. But if for some strange reason, you are writing to a single person exclusively, -or- you known that it is just Portuguese readers (reading English) you might be able to get away with 'Brasil'.
There is no issue in speech because they both pronounce the inner consonant  the same, and the difference in ending can be tolerated easily.

But let's presume, for the sake of being complete, that you have a word that is pronounced differently in the two languages.
You speak Brazilian Portuguese and use that pronunciation for your country and would do so with other Portuguese speakers there. But there is a dilemma if you are speaking to an English person in English in an English speaking country.
The bulk of your intuition and speaking over the years is geared towards saying the name properly -in- Portuguese. But you know the 'rules' of English and they are that you should say it the English way.
You probably want to be true to your country and yourself (and speak naturally) and say it the Brazilian way, but the English speaker might think it sounds weird (they surely won't have a problem with knowing that you're talking about 'Brazil').
If though your pronunciation is not understandable by the English speaker (or almost equivalently, the English version is distinct enough from, it may be easier to speak it their way, just to be understood. You're speaking in their context, and it's work for them to try to adjust to a set of patterns (Portuguese) that they may have no knowledge of.
Sure, tolerance on all sides is called for, but you also need to be aware of the competence of the speakers on both sides.
Also the social context matters. If you are giving a speech in English to English speakers about Brazil, it might be acceptable (even expected) to refer to the subject as 'Brasil', because of the shift in context of the subject.
Note: none of this is particular to English and Portuguese in that direction. An English person in Brazil should probably say 'Brasil'. A Chinese person speaking Vietnamese to a Vietnamese person will have the similar issues.

You're following the wrong rules. It's not unvoiced: intervocalic written ‹s› in Modern Portuguese is a voiced sibilant, not an unvoiced one like it is in Modern Spanish. See casa in various languages for this distinction. So it's mostly [bɾɐˈziɫ] in Portugal and mostly [bɾaˈziʊ̯] in Brasil. I bet he just wants to know the letters to write; I'm sure he already knows the sounds to say.

@tchrist I don't know Portuguese, I was just following along with what the OP seemed to say. In any case (with respect to the actual pronunciation), the varieties of what to do are still there. In the purported duplicate, I am very much in favor of RegDwights answer (the 'when in Rome...' variety), but there're always social contexts where it could be different. To be fair, when you're in Rome, the Romans do what they like, but it's weird if a non-Roman does anything but the Roman way.

/'bra zɪl/? I think (for the English pronunciation) you mean /bɹəˈzɪl/, with stress on the second syllable and a schwa in the first one.

@alphabet Yes, thanks. I am hesitant to correct at the moment only because it is unclear how to correct the /s/-/z/ thing without understanding what the OP is talking about, speech or writing.

But the answer is this: How does the OP want to sound when speaking English? So, really, it's an opinion thing. Since for me, only an opinion can be an answer here, maybe I should vote to close. The OP is talking about speech, come on. He even says so.

@Lambie If you're not wrong then prove it: tell us all what his "with an s" means, eh? There can be only one conclusion here.

@tchrist The OP understands Brasil versus Brazil. But really disappointing is that no one bothered to point out that this is an opinion question, not one about English per se.

Using "Brasil" (with an 's') when speaking or writing in English involves important considerations about language conventions, effective communication, and cultural identity. I believe the answer centers on the appropriateness or correctness of using the native spelling of your country's name in English contexts, and what impact this choice might have on clarity and perception among English speakers.
In standard English usage, the country is spelled "Brazil" with a 'z'. This spelling is universally recognized and aligned with English orthographic conventions. Major English dictionaries, such as the Oxford English Dictionary and Merriam-Webster, list "Brazil" as the standard spelling. Style guides used in professional and academic writing, like The Chicago Manual of Style, which advises using the English forms of foreign place names when they are well-established in the language, and the AP Stylebook, also endorse "Brazil".
Using "Brazil" is considered correct in English. It ensures immediate recognition among English speakers without causing confusion. It aligns with established linguistic practices, which is especially important in formal or professional settings. It avoids potential misunderstandings that could arise from using a less familiar spelling.
Using "Brasil" in English can affect clarity and may lead to misunderstandings:

Confusion: English speakers unfamiliar with the Portuguese spelling might perceive "Brasil" as a typo or may not immediately realize it refers to "Brazil".
Perception of Incompetence: Deviating from standard spelling conventions might lead others to question your proficiency in English or your attention to detail.
Distraction: The unexpected spelling could distract readers or listeners, causing them to focus on the anomaly rather than the content of your communication.

For example, if you write in a professional report, "Our operations in Brasil have expanded," some readers might be momentarily confused or think there's an error, which can detract from the overall professionalism of your work.
Cultural Identity and Code-Switching
Code-switching is the practice of alternating between languages or dialects within a conversation. Using "Brasil" in English is a form of code-switching that can reflect your cultural identity and personal connection to your homeland. There are several reasons why someone might choose to code-switch:

Cultural Pride: You might feel that "Brasil" better represents your heritage and want to share that with others.
Preference for Native Terms: Certain words may hold more meaning or feel more authentic when used in their original language.
Difficulty with Language Transition: As a non-native English speaker, you might occasionally revert to your native language out of habit or comfort.

However, when communicating with monolingual English speakers, code-switching could be confusing or disruptive. Choosing to use "Brasil" in English might lead to negative reactions:

Perceived Pedantry or Cultural Imposition: Some may view the consistent use of native terms as insisting on your cultural norms over established English conventions.
Questioning Competence: Listeners might assume you're unaware of the correct English spelling, potentially undermining your credibility.
Disruption of Communication Flow: Unfamiliar terms can momentarily disrupt understanding, drawing attention away from your intended message.

For instance, in a business meeting, stating "Our company is expanding its operations in Brasil" might prompt colleagues to focus on the spelling rather than the strategic information you're conveying. It's important to find a balance between honoring your cultural identity and ensuring clear communication. Here are some ways to navigate this:

Audience Awareness: Consider who you are speaking or writing to. If your audience is familiar with Brazilian culture or the Portuguese language, using "Brasil" might enrich the conversation. In general English-speaking contexts, especially with those unfamiliar with Portuguese, it's usually best to use "Brazil" to avoid confusion.
Context Matters: In informal settings, cultural discussions, or educational contexts where you're sharing aspects of Brazilian culture, introducing "Brasil" can add depth. For instance, "In Brasil—our Portuguese spelling for Brazil—we celebrate Carnival with great enthusiasm."
Provide Clarification: If you choose to use "Brasil", offer a brief explanation. For example, "I'm from Brasil—that's how we spell 'Brazil' in Portuguese."

For non-native English speakers, embracing Anglicisms—foreign words adapted into English usage—is crucial for achieving fluency and effective communication. While it might feel uncomfortable to use Anglicized terms for places significant to you, maybe it helps to view this practice as a tool for effective communication rather than a compromise of cultural identity. Many speakers from other countries with different native spellings face similar situations. For example, Germans refer to their country as "Germany" in English, though it's "Deutschland" in German.
Here's my specific advice on use of "Brazil" vs "Brasil" in English:

Use Standard English in Formal Contexts: In professional, academic, or formal communications, I would advise using the conventional English spelling "Brazil".
Introduce Native Terms Thoughtfully: When appropriate, share the native spelling as part of cultural exchange. For example, "Brazil (spelled 'Brasil' in Portuguese) is known for its vibrant festivals."
Assess the Audience and Setting: With friends or colleagues familiar with Brazilian culture, using "Brasil" might enhance the conversation.
Practice Adaptation: Regularly using "Brazil" in English contexts can help you become more comfortable with the Anglicized term, improving your overall fluency.

Embracing Anglicisms is a part of language fluency even though your cultural identity is a valuable aspect of who you are. While using "Brasil" when speaking or writing in English isn't incorrect in an absolute sense, it deviates from standard English conventions and may affect how your message is received. You can honor cultural identity by sharing insights about your culture when appropriate, using native terms in contexts where they enrich the conversation, and educating others about your heritage. Otherwise, stick to standard English.

Welcome back, nohat.

Just a few minutes ago on BBC Radio in reference to the devastating floods in Spain I was a tiny bit surprised to hear a reporter from the UK pronounce the name of the city of Valencia as /vəˈlɛn.θi.ə/ with northern (ᴀᴋᴀ “standard”) Spanish’s theta, not /vəˈlɛn.si.ə/ as most English speakers would automatically use. But he didn’t make the first sound a /b/ instead of /v/ as one would in Spanish’s /baˈlen.θja/. [...]

[...] Then again, unlike more northerly dialects of both Spanish and Catalan, the southern Catalan dialect spoken in that city does actually have a real /v/ phoneme there, and like English with schwas in unstressed syllables and one more syllable than Spanish would have: /vəˈlɛn.si.ə/. It was an interesting mix. He was on the ground reporting from that locale, so who knows what may have influenced him.
